# Laravel many to many relationship access value from Controller in blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two database table 
1. patient 
   --id 
   --name
2. report 
   --id
   --description
and pivot talbe 
patient_report 
  --id
  --report_id
  --patient_id

My Patient Model

```
class Patient extends Model
{ 
    public function reports()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Report' , 'patient_reports');
    }
}
```

My Report Model

```
class Report extends Model
{
    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient' , 'patient_reports');
    }
}
```

My ReportControlller

```
public function viewList($reportFloor = null)
{
    $report = Report::orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->paginate(50);
    return view('admin.report_list' , ['reports' => $report]);
}
```

Database : patients table have report_id column and reports table have patient_id column 
N.B : I want to find the patient name who has a report. And i am using the laravel dynamic properties like that --- 
And finally my blade

```
@foreach ($reports as $report)
    {{ $report->patients->name }}
@endforeach
```

But it provides an error like that 
[image: error like as]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($reports->patients as $patient)
    {{ $patient->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error implies, you're attempting to access the name attribute on a collection.  To fix you should change:

```
@foreach ($reports as $report)
    {{ $report->patients->name }}
@endforeach
```

to:

```
@foreach ($reports as $report)
    @foreach ($report->patients as $patient)
        {{ $patient->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: You'll need to provide additional information in order to receive assistance.  What didn't work exactly?  Are you getting the same error as before?  If not, are you receiving a new error now?  Also, you should probably update your post with pertinent sections of dd($report); (from within your Controller).

Comment: no error its provide newly.  dd its working right.   I have find output first loop but no output provide within second loop

Comment: @NazmulHossain If you don't have data for the related report it won't display anything and it will throw an error. @alaric you should also put the `foreach` statement inside `if & else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, i would first find the patients and afterwards get their reports.

```
$patients = Patient::with('reports')->get();
```

And then in the view i would do:

```
//This will first get all the patients
@foreach ($patients as $patient)

    // This will get each of patients relational reports
    @foreach ($patient->reports as $report)
        {{ $report->name }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```